# seems like $state.go has no effect on my app, it does nothing at all

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

hi guys i have tried to use the angular ui router but it seems to me like i can't in any way possible to use the $state.go it just does nothing.

my config:

```
    muApp.config([
      '$stateProvider', 
      '$locationProvider',  
      '$urlRouterProvider', 
       function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider.
      state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
      }).
      state('test', {
        url: '/test',
        templateUrl: 'templates/o.html',
        controller: 'testCtrl'
      }).
      state('login', {
        url: '/login',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'loginCtrl'
      });

    if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
  }]);
```

and when i try to use $state.go('login') for instance nothing happens at all.

```
muApp.factory('Auth', ['$rootScope', '$cookies', 'Restangular', '$state', function($rootScope, $cookies, Restangular, $state) {
    function getCurrentUser() {
        if ($rootScope.user) {
            // we already found the user so no need to check with the server again
            return $rootScope.user;
        }
        var login_needed = false;

        //if the user doesnt have this cookie it means he needs to login
        if (!$cookies.userid) {
            login_needed = true;
        }
        // if he does have his cookie lets ask the server if everything ok with this user [and get some info about our use]
        if (!login_needed) {
            Restangular.one('user', $cookies.userid).get().then(function (user) {
                //keep the user data in our scope
                $rootScope.user = user;
                return user;
            }, function() {
                // we failed, probably not authenticated user
                //TODO: shall we alert the user about his not working account?
                login_needed = true;
            });
        }
        if (login_needed) {
            console.log('before');
            $state.go('login');
            console.log('after');
            return null;
        }
    }

    return {
        getCurrentUser: function() {
            return getCurrentUser();
        }
    }
```

it prints to the console:

```
before
after
```

and the url stays /home or /test or whatever it was before.

i also tried to use $state.go in the controller itself and even in the app.run() and nothing.
i also tried $state.transitionTo('login') but it does nothing at all :( (just like $state.go

Comment: Did you add a reference to ui.router.state in your module?  Any errors in your console?

Comment: the console doesn't report any error and this is my module:
var muApp = angular.module('muApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'restangular', 'ngCookies']);
ill try to add ui.router.state

edit: i've added ui.router.state and seems like no effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok guys thx for the help i changed my old run block

from:

```
$rootScope.$on( "$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
    Auth.getCurrentUser();
});
```

to:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    console.log('in $stateChangeStart');
    if (toState.name != 'login') {
        event.preventDefault();
        Auth.getCurrentUser();
    }
});
```

which fixed the problem :)
it seems like that without the **event.preventDefault()** the url can't change

Comment: That doesnt sound right at all. Are you trying to NOT get to a state? Thats what event.preventDefault will do inside stateChangeStart

Comment: i tried to stop a state if the user is not logged in, and instead redirecting him to the login page

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this case is to add all state event listeners to $rootscope and console.log whats happening as in

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
  console.log('in $stateChangeStart'); 
})
```

Do the same for *$stateNotFound*, *$stateChangeError*, as well as *$viewContentLoading*

Also make sure that your 'loginCtrl' exists and is actually loaded and that the template url exists

P.S. just for kicks, see if this works when you DONT enable the html5mode

Comment: this is what i get  
   redirecting to login  
 in $stateChangeStart  
 finished redirecting to login  
 in $stateChangeStart

Comment: and i've added all the $stateNotFound, $stateChangeError, as well as $viewContentLoading
 also the html5 stuff didnt help :(

Comment: @user3324330 what was the cause of your problem?

Comment: my run block didnt use: event.preventDefault()